# R - Replace the first NAs in a vector

Tags: r

I need to replace the first NAs in a vector (for example: `cc = c(NA, NA, 1, 3, 4)`). I want to replace them with the first non-NA value (in this example, it'd be 1).

I have tried multiple methods, such as `zoo::na.locf` and `zoo::na.fill`, but they only work for the NAs in the middle of the vector, but not the beginning. Is there a way that I can get around this?

Comment: na.locf has a parameter called fromLast or something like that. And I'm assuming you meant na.fill from zoo not fill.na

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the `first` function from `dplyr` as below:

```
d = c(NA, NA, 1, 3, 4)

library(dplyr)
#first non-na value
a <- first(d[!is.na(d)])
#position of the first non-na value
b <- which(!is.na(d))[1]

#replace the first na values with the non-na from above
d[1:(b-1)] <- a
```

Output:

```
> d
[1] 1 1 1 3 4
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use `cumprod(is.na())` to make an index to the leading NAs; the `cumprod` will zero out any NAs in the middle or end. You'll also need to convert it back to logical, either with `as.logical` or double negation.

```
R>x <- c(NA, NA, 1,3,4)
R>cumprod(is.na(x))
[1] 1 1 0 0 0
R>i <- cumprod(is.na(x))
R>x[!!i] <- x[which.min(i)]
R>x
[1] 1 1 1 3 4
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the NA are always found in the lead? But if not, for completeness:

```
na.change <- function(vec){
if(sum(!is.na(vec))==0)return(vec)
if(sum(is.na(vec))==0)return(vec)
if(min(which(is.na(vec)))>max(which(!is.na(vec))))return(vec)# only trailing NAs
idx.min <- min(which(is.na(vec)))
idx.max <- min(which(!is.na(vec[idx.min:length(vec)])))-2+idx.min
vec[idx.min:idx.max] <- vec[idx.max+1]
return(vec)
}
```